# За счёт чего достигается кроссплатформенность какого-либо языка программирования?

Tags: любой-язык, кроссплатформенность

Хотелось бы понять, за счёт чего реализуется кроссплатформенность ЯП.

Comment: За счет стандартов, которым следуют авторы компиляторов (или интерпретаторов) Тут важно понимать, что программа на ЯП это всего лишь текст, смысл которого требуется отобразить на другом языке (машинный код + соглашения OS API)

Comment: За счёт наличия транслятора для каждой платформы.

Answer (score 0):

За счет кроссплатформенных фреймворков, возьми например NET и .NET Core, Java, С++, на уровне компиляции, имеют кроссплатформенные компиляторы